# android using Bluetooth without activity

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I want to write a library project in android to scan Bluetooth devices and return list of devices. The library project does not have an activity. In the library project I will write getListOfBlueTooth function. Or I will provide Interface to be implemented in the client app to communicate. It may be looks like the SDK project of Facebook.

I will create a client application and from the client application I will invoke getListOfBlueTooth devices API of my library. Or I can communicate with library by implementing the Interfaces of the Library project. That is in the client application I don’t need to know how the logic is implemented in the Bluetooth device listing.

My question is, is it possible to invoke the startDiscovery() function of BlueToothAdapter without an activity class. Because, I read that I need to register for ACTION_FOUND to be notified as remote Bluetooth devices are found. For this I need to use broadcast receiver and IntentFilter. Hope I have explained my problem clearly. Is is possible? Could you please give me advice?